# AWS RDS(MySQL) Unable to edit parameter

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS mysql 8.x and trying to create a trigger.

Got error when tried to create a trigger.

> ERROR 1419: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is
> enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe
> log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

So, I would like to execute the following statement.

```
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

Since, it is not allowed without a super admin privilege, I tried to modify the parameter thru AWS admin console.

[image]

Getting the error below. What else can be done for this.

> Error saving: Cannot modify a default parameter group. (Service:
> AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue;
> Request ID: 147e8872-865a-4269-b9f8-aa95654a800e; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 2):

on AWS RDS, you are not allowed to modify the DEFAULT parameter groups. But you are allowed to modify YOUR own parameter groups. And you can associate YOUR RDS database to YOUR parameter groups.

What you should do:

1. go to the AWS console, navigate to RDS, navigate to "parameter groups",
2. click on "create parameter group", select your database type [to which you'll associate this new parameter group] and give it any name,
3. once created, navigate back to the list of "parameter groups", click on the newly created parameter group. You will see the list of all parameters for your new paramter group, then filter for the string "log_bin_trust_function_creators", then click on "edit parameters", then set log_bin_trust_function_creators=1, then click "save changes"
4. navigate to your RDS database, change the parameter group [your database is currently associated to the "default parameter group"] to your new parameter group (created in the previous steps),
5. restart your RDS database.

NOTE: the message says that "you don't have SUPER privs" but you will never have SUPER privileges in AWS RDS. Therefore, your only option is to perform the above steps.